# Why does \IfStrEqCase print the url of \href?

Tags: biblatex, xstring

## Motivation

I'm writing a biblatex bbx file for philosophers, and I want to include eprint support (like that which is builtin for arXiv) for the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/). The SEP requests that citations to their articles cite a specific version. The versions are updated in seasonal blocks, and the urls are used to identify them in the following scheme: `plato.stanford.edu/archives/<season-code><year>/<article-slug>` where `<year>` is the year of the version, `<article-slug>` is a unique identifier for the article, and `<season>` is one of `spr`,`sum`, `fall`, and `wint`.

I want to write my biblatex eprint printer so that it prints the article slug as a hyperlink to the relevant versioned entry.

## Specific technical problem

It's easy to store and retrieve the season in biblatex, and I'm storing the slug in in the `eprint` field. The problem is that the season codes above are different from the season *names* (or even the raw localisation strings) that biblatex uses. So, I intended to use `\IfStrEqCase` from `xstring` to compare the season of the entry with each of the four season localisation strings, and then return the relevant season str for use with the sep url. I was going to put this inside the text of the link in the `\href` call to build the url.

The problem is that the call to `\IfStrEqCase` doesn't expand inside `\href`. Instead the whole url (the first arg to `\href` is printed, followed by the intended display text. (i.e. `plato.stanford.edu/archives/spr2020/prob-percprob-perc`)

How can I make the case statement expand properly?

## MWE

A minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{sep-foo,
    eprint = {perception-problem},
    eprinttype = {sep},
    date = {2021-21},
    author = {Crane, Tim and Craig French},
    title = {The Problem of Perception},
}
\end{filecontents}

% Declare my own style
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{href-prob.bbx}
[\abx@bbxid]

% Basis to alter
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear}

\RequirePackage{xstring}

\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:sep}{%
  \href{www.example.com/%
    \IfStrEqCase{\bibstring{\thefield{season}}}{%
      {\bibstring{spring}}{spr}%
      {\bibstring{summer}}{sum}%
      {\bibstring{autumn}}{fall}% 
      {\bibstring{winter}}{wint}}%
      }{#1}}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.cbx}
\ProvidesFile{href-prob.cbx}
[\abx@cbxid]

\RequireCitationStyle{authoryear-ibid}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=\jobname]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Foo bar. \autocite{sep-foo}

\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within `\hyperref` or `\url` you probably want commands that are expandable, so that the argument can actually expand to the complete URL.

I don't think `\IfStrEqCase` is expandable. For the use case shown in the question, where you essentially need to replace one string by another, I would go for a solution that is based on predefined macros.

Specifically we define macros called `hpblx@season@<season in biblatex lingo>` with replacement text `<season in SEP lingo>`. These macros can then be used with `\csuse`.

Note that in `biblatex` v3.17 and above `season` is called `yeardivision`. (See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/doc/latex/biblatex/CHANGES.md and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki/Changes-to-the-standard-styles.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\csdef{hpblx@season@spring}{spr}
\csdef{hpblx@season@summer}{sum}
\csdef{hpblx@season@autumn}{fall}
\csdef{hpblx@season@winter}{wint}

\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:sep}{%
  \href{https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/%
    \ifcsundef{hpblx@season@\thefield{yeardivision}}
      {}
      {\csuse{hpblx@season@\thefield{yeardivision}}}%
    \thefield{year}/entries/%
    \thefield{eprint}}
    {SEP: \texttt{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{sep-foo,
  eprint     = {perception-problem},
  eprinttype = {sep},
  date       = {2021-21},
  author     = {Crane, Tim and Craig French},
  title      = {The Problem of Perception},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo bar. \autocite{sep-foo}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: SEP link]